# Adding style to php file

Tags: php, pfbc

I am using PFBC a package made available by google to create my forms because I am new to php and I have a project I need to complete quickly anyway i'm just trying to center the Capacha block in the middle of my div I know I have to connect it with my style in css I just don't know how to go about adding this to my PHP

this is the Capatcha.php file all the elements are broken up in separate php files

```
<?php
namespace PFBC\Element;

class Captcha extends \PFBC\Element {
    protected $privateKey = "";
    protected $publicKey = "";

    public function __construct($label = "", array $properties = null) {
        parent::__construct($label, "recaptcha_response_field", $properties);
    }   

    public function render() {
        $this->validation[] = new \PFBC\Validation\Captcha($this->privateKey);
        require_once(__DIR__ . "/../Resources/recaptchalib.php");
        echo recaptcha_get_html($this->publicKey);
    }
}
```

this is how it gets rendered

```
    // reCAPTCHA with validation, automaticallly required
$form->addElement(new Element\Captcha("Validation:", array(
    "longDesc" => "This is a <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA\">
    reCaptcha test</a> to reduce spam submissions.",
)));
```

Comment: You are way over your head im afraid. And this question is far too vague. Probably you need to hire a programmer if this is urgent

Comment: Find where `$captcha->render()` is being called and wrap that in your style stuff.

Comment: Really hope those aren't your actual keys.

Comment: the keys are still visible in the edit history, you can't change that.  Generate some new keys urgently!

Comment: The keys are the same for everyone anyway if anyone is use to the PFBC package and can help would be much appreciated thank you